# Racket Programming - my map

Tags: if-statement, scheme, lisp, conditional-statements, racket

How would you replace the `cond` to an `if else` in this program?

```
#lang racket

(define (my-map f lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [else (cons (f (first lst))
                (my-map f (rest lst)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `cond` expression with just one condition and a single expression as the consequent and an `else` part with a single expression as the alternative can be easily transformed into an `if` expression. For example, this:

```
(cond (<cond1> <exp1>)
      (else <exp2>))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(if <cond1> ; condition
    <exp1>  ; consequent
    <exp2>) ; alternative
```

In particular, your code can be rewritten as:

```
(define (my-map f lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (cons (f (first lst))
            (my-map f (rest lst)))))
```

Also notice that a `cond` is just a shorter way to express a series of nested `if` expressions. Think of it as a shorthand for `IF-ELSE IF-ELSE IF-ELSE` in other programming languages. In fact, for the general case many interpreters implement this:

```
(cond (<cond1> <exp1> <exp2>) ; we can have any number of conditions
      (<cond2> <exp3> <exp4>) ; and any number of expressions after condition
      (else <exp5> <exp 6>))
```

... As a syntactical transformation that (ignoring the `=>` syntax) gets expanded into:

```
(if <cond1>
    (begin
      <exp1>
      <exp2>)
    (if <cond2>
        (begin
          <exp3>
          <exp4>)
        (begin      ; the last expression is the `else` part
          <exp5>
          <exp6>)))
```

Notice that the expressions after each condition are inside a `begin` form, meaning that in a `cond` they're implicitly inside a `begin` - so you can write more than one! whereas in an `if` expression only a single expression can go in either the consequent or the alternative, and if more than one is needed a `begin` must be used. As always, refer to the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Every cond:

```
(cond (predicate consequent)
      (predicate2 consequent2-1 consequent2-2)
      (else alternative))
```

Can be rewritten:

```
(if predicate 
    consequent
    (if predicate2
        (begin
           consequent2-1
           consequent2-2)
         alternative))
```

Your example becomes particularly simple because there is not more than 2 clauses and the code does not make use of explicit begin.

Answer (score 0):

Racket isn't really Scheme as, for example, Racket requires a different `if` syntax than Scheme.  But, figuring that you are, in fact, learning Scheme you might check out the Scheme R7RS Specification; it provides a definition of `cond` in terms of `if`.  Here is a definition that I've simplified for you by axing templates involving '=>':

```
(define-syntax cond
  (syntax-rules (else)
    ((cond (else result1 result2 ...))
     (begin result1 result2 ...))
    ((cond (test)) test)
    ((cond (test) clause1 clause2 ...)
     (let ((temp test))
       (if temp temp
           (cond clause1 clause2 ...))))
    ((cond (test result1 result2 ...))
     (if test (begin result1 result2 ...)))
    ((cond (test result1 result2 ...)
           clause1 clause2 ...)
     (if test
         (begin result1 result2 ...)
         (cond clause1 clause2 ...)))))
```

Beautiful, yes?